# Is it rude to say "damn it"?

Tags: translation, offensive-language, portuguese

The context: Not connected with anything. Just sharing a feeling when nobody asked, like:

> "Damn it, I love ice cream."

Is it rude to write or say it in UK? Australia and New Zealand? USA?

I would like to express in English what someone might say in Brazilian Portuguese:

> "Caramba/que droga/que coisa, eu gosto de ..."

possibly as a conversation starter.

Comment: Every question I ask in StackExchange websites is closed because of something. Damn it!

Comment: Whether an expression is offensive is something that is well within the scope of this site. Those who voted to close this question as opinion-based presumably did so because people may differ in whether they perceive this expression as offensive, but these differences can be explained, and the explanation would not itself be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Can you add something about the Portuguese terms so we understand what you intend by the use of 'damn it'?

Comment: There are some people (in the US and the UK) who will be offended.

Comment: I really don't know how can I study a language without having people opinions. I want to know how would they feel if I say something.
I read some and they are really good, thanks you all. I think I got the point and I have been used to not so appropriate occasions, and now I will be careful to it do not happen.

PS: WE all know StackExchange in general suffer a ego problem and there are many memes about how the moderators deal with the questions, always finding a reason to close it.

Comment: "Damn it, I love ice cream." is not offensive in BE, but in BE, "Damn it, I love ice cream." is seen as an Americanism, and is rarely used. On a broader note, "damn" in BE has been reduced to a simple, semi-forceful, emphatic. I suspect that nobody is truly upset at hearing it.

Answer (score 4):

*Damn* (in its religious sense) was once considered quite a strong expletive, but nowadays obscenities are considered more taboo than religious 'swear words'. That being said, it would only be appropriate in informal conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Quite rude. But if you use it in an informal conversation with your friends, nobody will be confused, I think. And if you use it with your colleagues, for example... well, it may be not a good idea :)

Comment: Less rude options could include:
Wow, I love I cream.
Boy, I love ice cream.
Oh my, I love ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, most people regarded **any** use of religion-related language for frivolous, nonreligious purposes as improper. Their religious sentiments would have been accordingly offended by somebody's using *damn*, a term that they perceived as expressing a religious concept of tremendous significance, to express a mundane feeling.

Nowadays, a number of people who would be thus offended is much smaller. On one side, the people who are religious have become much more used to being surrounded by, and regularly interacting with, those of no religion, and have consequently developed greater tolerance of different views on such matters. Second, most people now don't perceive the use of *damn* as an exclamation with very little definite meaning to be related to the religious concept of damnation; they would need to pause and think to see that they are related. The original reasons for avoiding *damn* thus continue to apply only when one is interacting with a relatively small minority of deeply religious people who still cultivate the traditional sensitivities about such matters.

This, of course, does not mean that it is OK to use *damn* as an exclamation in just any context: it belongs to a fairly informal register. Using it in a casual conversation among friends is generally OK, but people may perceive its use as rude in a context that calls for greater formality, in the same way in which they would perceive as rude any other term that doesn't fit the level of formality that the occasion calls for.

Answer (score -1):

[Merriam-Webster says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damn) that the use of the word *damn* is "impolite" and that it "may offend."

That which is *impolite* is also *rude*. And to offend other people is to be rude.

Therefore the answer is: *Yes*.

*It is rude* to say “damn it.”

Comment: *Impolite* is commonly less serious than *rude*. There's a big grey area between *polite* and *rude*, full of things that aren't really one or the other.

Comment: I disagree. An action is either polite or rude.